# Is it possible to rerender partial objects instead whole scene in Three.js in the animation loop?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I have a video texture which obviously needs to be updated/repainted to have the video frame after frame as video in my Three.js scene:

```
            let video_geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(150, 32);
            let video = document.getElementById('video');
            video.play();
            let video_texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
            video_texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            video_texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            video_texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
            video_texture.repeat.set(0.6, 1);
            let video_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, map: video_texture });
            let circle_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(video_geometry, video_material);

            scene.add(circle_mesh);


            let animate = ()=>{
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera); // can I here only rerender the circle_mesh?
            }

            animate();
```

How can I only rerender the object with the video and not the whole scene which did not change at all to save performance?

Comment: Easy, instead of rendering to screen, first render everything except the video onto a texture (you'll need to save both the color and the depth buffers). Then each frame use `gl.blitFramebuffer` to copy those 2 buffers onto the screen, then you can render your video normally.

Comment: You'll need to use `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` for more info google "threejs render to texture"

Comment: 1. Save the scene that hasn't changed to a texture with [`WebGLRenderTarget`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget). 2. On frame update, render this texture as the background, with the new video frame on top of it. Should only be 2 drawcalls!